# How to use RegularExpression in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find a particular pattern in the content of textfile. can anybody help me with coding how to implement this in c# .net using regularexpression(with syntax)?

Comment: You will have to do a little bit more explaining than that. Have you any idee the depth of Regex???

Comment: a sample of the content would be required for someone here to formulate a regex for you. Also you should tag this question with regex. For help on how to use that regex in C# check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend, give it a try.
http://www.google.com.pk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=regular+expression+c%23+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&psj=1&fp=9045c49e6667deb3

Answer (score 0):

This basically depends on the pattern you want to identify. As others stated, you should be more specific about your pattern expectations.
First off, you need to get a basic knowledge on Regular Expression Syntax (usually POSIX, historically UNIX, but it is a cross-language/platform syntax) : Take a look at [this reference site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Then go to your favorite c# editor and type this :

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(yourtextfilepath);
string input;
string pattern = @"\b(\w+)\s\1\b";//Whatever Regular Expression Pattern goes here
while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
{
   input = sr.ReadLine();
   Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
   if (matches.Count > 0)
   {          
      foreach (Match match in matches)
         //Print it or whatever 
         Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   }
}
sr.Close();
```